# Как перемещать текст по странице сайта в css?

Tags: css, css3, text

Есть блок, и на нем должны быть размещены различные фразы-ссылки. Одну из них мне нужно переместить вправо на некоторое количество пикселей.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте свойство `margin-left`:

```css
#link2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
  <a href="#" id="link1">link1</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" id="link2">link2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" id="link3">link3</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" id="link4">link4</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" id="link5">link5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы они все билы на одной линии ???

Comment: @Bernard то есть что бы все были сдвинуты? Если да, то в css пропиши `#links a {margin-left: 15px;}`. 
А вообще, советую самоучитель какой-нибудь почитать...